# Two consecutive OracleDataAdapter updates inside a TransactionScope

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, odp.net

I need to execute some insert instructions from a typed DataSet to a set of tables in my Oracle DB

I do something like:

```
OracleDataAdapter da1 = new OracleDataAdapter();
da1.InsertCommand = previouslyInitializedCommand;

OracleDataAdapter da2 = new OracleDataAdapter();
da2.InsertCommand = anotherCommand()
...
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
using (OracleConnecction conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
{
    da1.InsertCommand.Connection = conn;
    da2.InsertCommand.Connection = conn;

    da1.Update(dataset.Table1);
    da2.Update(dataset.Table2);

    ts.Complete();
}
```

The second Update never happens because the first one change the row status of Table2 to "Unmodified". Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Is there any relation between `Table1` and `Table2`?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici Yes, Table1 and Table2 are connected by a DataRelation with cascade constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works...

I have done two things:

1. Changed from the dataset designer the accept/reject rule of the relation that links Table1 to Table2 from Cascade to None.
2. I have set the UpdatedRowSource to Both.